# Empty default case in partial switch vs if sentence

Tags: c#, sonarqube, sharpdevelop

Suppose you have an `enum` type like this:

```
public enum Type
{
    A, B, C, D, E, F
}
```

Then you want to do something depending on some of the values, so you create a switch sentence:

```
switch (type)
{
    case Type.A: // Do something
        break;
    case Type.B: // Do something
        break;
    case Type.C: // Do something
        break;
}
```

This compiles and works fine, but then Sonarqube 5.2 (with the default rules for C#) examines the code and complains about the `switch` not having a default case (it qualifies it as a major issue). So you change the code to this:

```
switch (type)
{
    case Type.A: // Do something
        break;
    case Type.B: // Do something
        break;
    case Type.C: // Do something
        break;
    default: // Do nothing
        break;
}
```

But then it's SharpDevelop who complains, graying the default case and telling you that the code should not be there as it does nothing.

So you end up changing the code to an `if` sentence:

```
if (type == Type.A) // Do something
else if (type == Type.B) // Do something
else if (type == Type.C) // Do something
```

With this code, neither SonarQube nor SharpDevelop complain at all. Well, SharpDevelop kindly suggests that the `if` can be converted into a `switch`.

So, which way is better? Should I add the default case to the `switch` and ignore SharpDevelop? Should I ignore the issue in SonarQube? Or should I just go for the `if` sentence? Is there any other way to do it more properly?

Comment: seriously you should not have multiple extensions for VS that conflict with each other. i suggest remove them all and just install resharper ;)... use switch without default. also use your brain!.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary I'm not using Visual Studio, but SharpDevelop. And SonarQube is part of our continuous integration environment, we're not using it as a plugin.

Comment: oh. sorry for that. i did not know this. but your question is opinion based anyway.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary Let me translate. The SharpDevelop suggestions are like Resharper and the SonarQube are like Code Analysis.

Comment: For the `default` case you should have something like: `throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid case: " + type);`

Comment: @MatthewWatson We have many `switch`es with the `InvalidOperationException`-throwing in the default case, but in this case we really don't care about the other options of the `enum`. As roryap says, maybe it is a smell of refactoring.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, you should always have a default case in my opinion.  I throw an exception in the default case because it indicates that there is something that I forgot to code (usually an added enum value, for example) and makes it clearly evident where the bug is.

What you do, of course, depends on what the default case implies in your application.  Is there truly a state where "do nothing" is an okay path through the code?  That's usually indicative of a defect or brittle code that should lead to refactoring.  The same goes for `if` blocks without `else` which you proposed as a work-around.  In fact, I'm surprised sonarqube doesn't complain about that, too.

Comment: I agree. Not having `default` throw an exception (or perform some default logic) can have similar consequences to "swallowing" an exception.

Comment: I suppose that you can never say that an empty default case is always incorrect, but I will check my code to see if that's our case. Maybe we are lacking throwing an exception, or maybe it's a smell, as you say.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo -- I agree, it's not *always* incorrect, but in my experience, it's rare...apparently sonarqube agrees, hence the error/warning you got.